# Show that $(x^2 + 1)$ is a maximal ideal of the ring $\mathbb Z_7[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra

So what I initially thought is that $\mathbb Z_7$[X] is a field, but now I'm questioning myself. I know that $\mathbb Z_7$ is a field.

And I know that if the quotient ring is a field then $(x^2 +1)$ has to be maximal.

Comment: $\Bbb Z_7[x]$ is not a field since, for example, $x$ has no multiplicative inverse in $\Bbb Z_7[x]$.  In general, if $F$ is a field then $F[x]$ is a principal ideal domain (actually $F[x]$ is a Euclidean domain).

Comment: @tilper Ok thank you, this helps me understand it better

Comment: Hint: An ideal m inside a commutative ring A is maximal iff A/m is a field.

Comment: @Mihail Yeah I know that, but A/m isn't a field in this case

Comment: Also an interesting but not very related is the fact that:  An ideal p inside a commutative ring A is prime iff A/p is a principal ideal domain.

Comment: @Mihail Again, I know this, but it is so irrelevant

Comment: $A/m$ is a field in this case.  $A = \Bbb Z_7[x]$ and $m = (x^2+1)$.

Comment: @Daniel $\mathbb{Z}_7 [x] /(x^2+1)$ is a field

Comment: @Mihail See this is the part I'm doubting myself on. How is it a field, that's what I need explaining to me

Comment: @DanielMcElroy I have actually shown that $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(x^2+1)$ is a field in my answer. I have provided two approaches.

Comment: @C.Falcon Yeah sorry, I've just been misreading it

Answer (score 3):

Since $\mathbb{Z}_7[X]$ is principal (it is euclidean), then $(x^2+1)$ is maximal if and only if $x^2+1$ is irreducible. Since $x^2+1$ has degree $2$, it is irreducible if and only if it has no roots, which is the case by inspection.

If you want to involve more machinery, $-1$ is a square in $\mathbb{Z}_p$, $p$ prime if and only if $p=2$ or $p\equiv 1\bmod 4$.

Alternatively, you can show that $(x^2+1)$ is maximal, since $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(x^2+1)$ is a field. Indeed, let $\overline{f}\in\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(x^2+1)\setminus\{0\}$, then $x^2+1$ does not divide $f$. Therefore, since $x^2+1$ is irreducible, using Bezout's theorem, there exists $(u,v)\in\mathbb{Z}_7[x]^2$ such that:
$$fu+(x^2+1)v=1.$$
Finally, $\overline{f}\overline{u}=\overline{1}$ and $\overline{f}$ is invertible.

Comment: How is $Z_7$[X] a field? what is the multiplicative inverse of x

Comment: I have never said that $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]$ is a field read carefully, $\mathbb{Z}_7[x]/(x^2+1)$ is though.

Comment: @Daniel Inverse of $x$ inside  $\mathbb{Z}_7 [x] /(x^2+1)$ is $-x$. Because $-x^2=(1+x^2)-x^2=1$.

Comment: @C.Falcon Yeah I'm reading it wrong my mistake. Could I ask another question or should i make a separate question? I want to know how to show (x) is a prime ideal in $Z$[X]

Comment: @DanielMcElroy It is another problem, not too much related to this one. You should probably ask another question.

Comment: @C.Falcon ok thanks

Comment: @DanielMcElroy You can use [Mihail's comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2292418/show-that-x2-1-is-a-maximal-ideal-of-the-ring-z-7x#comment4716056_2292418) to get started on that.

Comment: @tilper Yeah i basically need to show that Z[X]/(x) is an integral domain. And I think I do this by saying that x is irreducible and z[X] is a PID

Comment: Can you show that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/(x)\cong\mathbb{Z}$? Hints: use the evaluation map at $0$ and the first isomorphism theorem.

Comment: @C.Falcon Yeah that's what I thought also because its isomorphic to x where x is a integer. Ah, i've just realised that then it must be an integral domain